Gracefully exit the celery tasks in ForkPoolWorker
Simplified version of my task:
for _ in range(100000):
    # Check if worker is not shutting downed
    # if yes, exit gracefully

    # else, Do something.

I tried using this to handle SIGTERM on worker
@worker_shutting_down.connect
def worker_shutting_down_handler(sig, how, exitcode, ** kwargs):
    # Set worker_is_shutting_down

The problem is that worker_shutting_down.connect is only handled by the main process of celery. the ForkPoolWorkers have no idea about it.
How to propagate this message from Main process to all ForkPoolworkers?
few notes:

I can't set time_limit on the task since the task needs to be long running. it's designed that way.
I don't have problem calling them again, but it's important that they gracefully exit for some teardown work.
Already tried worker_process_shutdown.connect, but it's called only after the shutdown was successful in a ForkPoolProcess.


maybe not the greatest solution for this, but it fairly works well.
Since the file system is same for all the ForkPoolWorkers, I am using a file as a signal to shutdown.
from pathlib import Path
from celery.signals import (
    worker_shutting_down,
)

@worker_shutting_down.connect
def worker_shutting_down_handler(*_args, **_kwargs):
    """
    Worker is shutting down
    """
    Path('/tmp/worker_shutting_down').touch()


In the task
def should_gracefully_exit():
    """
    Check if the tasks should gracefully exit
    """
    return os.path.isfile("/tmp/worker_shutting_down")

def task():
    for _ in range(100000):
        if should_gracefully_exit()
            #teardown

        # else, Do something.


